# Swift: Unable to parse JSON response to model

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, objectmapper

I am getting data response from server like below:

```
{
   "success": true,
   "data": {
      "cash": 0,
      "newCash": 0,
      "cashExpireAt": "2019-02-26T16:01:35.6451887+08:00",
      "isEnabled": false,
      "low_balance": true
    }
}
```

//Below is Model Class

```
class WalletBalance: Mappable {

   var isSuccess               : Bool! = false
   var data                    : WalletData?

   required init?(map: Map) {
      //Code here
   }

   func mapping(map: Map) {
      isSuccess <- map["success"]
      data <- map["data"]
   }
}

class WalletData: Mappable {

   var cash                     : Int! = 0
   var newCash                  : Int! = 0
   var cashExpireAt             : String! = ""
   var isEnabled                : Bool! = false
   var low_balance              : Bool! = false

   required init?(map: Map) {
      //Code here
   }

   func mapping(map: Map) {
      cash <- map["cash"]
      newCash <- map["newCash"]
      cashExpireAt <- map["cashExpireAt"]
      isEnabled <- map["isEnabled"]
      low_balance <- map["low_balance"]
   }
}
```

//Below is code to call server api

```
Alamofire.request(url!, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: walletHeaders)
    .validate(statusCode: 200..<600)
    .responseObject { (response: DataResponse<WalletBalance>) in
         switch response.result {
         case .success:
            if response.result.value == nil {
               //Code here
            } else {
               completion(response.result.value!)
            }
         break
         case .failure(let error):
            print("error: ", error.localizedDescription)
         break
       }
     }
```

I am getting error:

> error:  The operation couldn’t be completed. ObjectMapper failed to
>   serialize response.

I tried to call api using postman but its working fine in Postman.

Comment: print("error: \(error)") instead of its localizedDescription? It might give more infos.

Comment: @Larme getting error _Error Domain=com.alamofireobjectmapper.error Code=2 "ObjectMapper failed to serialize response." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=ObjectMapper failed to serialize response.}_

Comment: You might have some value from your response that are empty or not defined

Comment: @Larme or simply `print("Error:", error)`

Comment: @ShivJaiswal forget about object mapper. You should use Swift 4 Codable protocol

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `Decodable` instead of `Mappable` as suggested by the [Alamofire documentation](https://github.com/sua8051/AlamofireMapper)?

Comment: Then try giving your variables a default value `var cash: Int? = 0`, `var cashExpireAt: String? = ""` and so on. Most probably one of the field in the result is `nil` @ShivJaiswal

Comment: Can you post how you replaced your current variables implementation to match a default values? I guess one of the values is empty or null and therefore if it doesn't have a default value it will fail to serialize. Please update the code to see what can we do and retry if it still gives you the same error.

Comment: @ShivJaiswal please try also to do `responseJSON` instead of `responseObject` as you are expecting a json as response composed of dictionary key values type.

Comment: @ShivJaiswal and also: `var data: WalletData()`

Answer (score 1):

Use `Decodable`. It's much easier, more efficient, built-in and it generates much less code. The date can be decoded directly as `Date`

```
let jsonString = """
{
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "cash": 0,
    "newCash": 0,
    "cashExpireAt": "2019-02-26T16:01:35.6451887+08:00",
    "isEnabled": false,
    "low_balance": true
  }
}
"""

struct Balance : Decodable {
    let success : Bool
    let data : Wallet
}

struct Wallet: Decodable {
    let cash, newCash : Int
    let cashExpireAt : Date
    let isEnabled, lowBalance : Bool
}


let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)
let decoder = JSONDecoder()

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
do {
    let result = try decoder.decode(Balance.self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch { print(error) }
```